# Point free monadic expression

Tags: haskell

Consider this expression (taken from Real World Haskell ch. 8, which I try to simplify)

```
isElfFile :: FilePath -> IO Bool
isElfFile path = return . hasElfMagic =<< L.readFile path
```

How do I make a point-free version of this function? I tried using its the other bind operation `>>=`, lifting `hasElfMagic`, but none seems to be working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simpler without binding here:

```
isElfFile path = return . hasElfMagic =<< L.readFile path
isElfFile path = fmap hasElfMagic (L.readFile path)
isElfFile      = fmap hasElfMagic . L.readFile
```

But of course also doable with `=<<`:

```
isElfFile path = return . hasElfMagic =<< L.readFile path
isElfFile path = (=<<) (return . hasElfMagic) (L.readFile path)
isElfFile      = (=<<) (return . hasElfMagic) . L.readFile
isElfFile      = (return . hasElfMagic =<<) . L.readFile
```

In general, it helps to convert infix functions into prefix form before trying make things point-free.

Comment: There is also `f <=< g = (f =<<) . g`, for cases where you can't just use `fmap`.

Comment: Well recommended. You could do `return . hasElfMagic <=< L.readFile` or if you prefer, `L.readFile >=> return. haseElfMagic`. The handy`>=>` from Control.Monad composes monadic functions with types like `a -> m b`. In a sense, it's a better way to think of monads, because if you define `>=>` and `return` instead of `>>=` and `return`, the monad laws become the much easier to understand three `f >=> return = f`, `return >=> f = f`, and `f >=> (g >=> h) = (f >=> g) >=> h`.